# Pure data sound effect library running on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, puredata

I wonder if someone managed to use [Pure data](http://puredata.info/) sound library as an external library of the an iOS app. [Pure data wiki](http://puredata.info/docs/developer/BuildingPdForiPhone) claims it can be compiled only on jailbroken iOS device. [iPD project](http://code.google.com/p/ipd/) claims to be 'Pd ported to iPhone OS to be used as an audio/control engine', but it doesn't mention anything considering wheteher it can only be deployed to jailbroken devices.

Has anyone made the pure data library to work on iOS device app, which successfully got approved by AppStore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of apps in the Apple App Store that include Pure Data, iJam, rjdj and Inception come to mind.  You want to use the 'libpd' version of Pd, its the version meant for embedding into things like iOS/Android apps, python/java/Processing/OpenFrameworks, etc.

Here's the home of libpd:
https://github.com/libpd

Comment: this source repo has moved to github, I'm going to edit this answer.

Comment: I'll point to http://www.mobmuplat.com/ for faster Pure Data app prototyping without needing xcode etc.